# Install4j: Updater log file name with timestamp

Tags: java, install4j

I have a SilentUpdater (built with Install4j version 6.1.4) which writes a logfile to a certain directory I have configured via VM paramters: `-Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=${installer:sys.installationDir}/log/updater.log`.

But this process always overwrites the previous updater log. So I am thinking of writing the log file with the execution timestamp. I have tried using `sys.date` and `sys.time` variable like the following: 
`-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=
${installer:sys.installationDir}/log/updater_${compiler:sys.date}_${compiler:sys.time}.log`

But I endup having the same file even though the updater was executed in different times. After reading in the documentation about the two variables, I think they are defined during the installer build process and are always the same.

So, is there any alternative way to have a log file with current timestamp either via VM parameter or during the execution of the update process?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 6.1.4 there is no solution for this problem. I've added this to the issue tracker.

---

**Update 2019-02-05**

In install4j 8, you will be able to use installer variables in `-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile` or its new alias `-Dinstall4j.log`. Passing `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` will no longer be necessary.

For timestamping, install4j 8 has installer variables `${installer:sys.date}`, `${installer:sys.time}` and `${installer:sys.timestamp}` that contain the time when the installer was started.